# Why the output is not correct and compelete when using pointers in array of structures?

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I have written this code using array of structures in C++ and the output was correct, but when I included the pointers, the output is not correct and missing a lot of, what is the reason of this?
This is the code using pointers:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct Course {
    string CourseCode;
    string CourseName;
    string LecturerName;
};

struct Student {
    string StudentID;
    string StudentName;
    string Nickname;
    Course info;
};

void menu(void) {
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    cout << "              MENU              " << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl;
    cout << "     1- Add new students" << endl;
    cout << "     2- Display student list" << endl;
    cout << "     3- Add new course" << endl;
    cout << "     4- Display Course Offered" << endl;
    cout << "     5- Exit Program" << endl;
    cout << "=================================" << endl << endl;
}

int main()
{
    Student *ptr[2] ;
    Student details[2];
    ptr[2] = &details[2];

    int m, option, courNo;

    menu();
    cout << "Choose an option from the menu: ";
    cin >> option;

    while (option != 5)
    {
        if (option == 1) {
           // cout << "\nHow many students do you want to enter? ";
           // cin >> stuNo;

            for (m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                cout << "\nEnter student " << m + 1 << " details: " << endl;
                cout << "ID: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->StudentID;
                cout << "Name: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->StudentName;
                cout << "Nickname: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->Nickname;
            }
        }

        else if (option == 2) {
            cout << "\nThe students details you entered are:" << endl;
            for (m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                cout << "\nStudent " << m + 1 << ": " << endl;
                cout << "ID: " << ptr[m]->StudentID << endl;
                cout << "Name: " << ptr[m]->StudentName << endl;
                cout << "Nickname: " << ptr[m]->Nickname << endl;
            }
        }

        else if (option == 3) {
            cout << "\nHow many courses do you want to enter? ";
            cin >> courNo;
            for (m = 0; m < courNo; m++) {
                cout << "\nEnter course " << m + 1 << " details: " << endl;
                cout << "Course Code: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->info.CourseCode;
                cout << "Course Name: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->info.CourseName;
                cout << "Lecturer Name: ";
                cin >> ptr[m]->info.LecturerName;
            }
        }

        else if (option == 4) {
            cout << "\nThe courses details you entered are:" << endl;
            for (m = 0; m < 2; m++) {
                cout << "\nCourse " << m + 1 << ": " << endl;
                cout << "Course Code: " << ptr[m]->info.CourseCode << endl;
                cout << "Course Name: " << ptr[m]->info.CourseName << endl;
                cout << "Lecturer Name: " << ptr[m]->info.LecturerName << endl;
            }
        }

        else
            cout << "Invalid number! Please re-enter a choice from the menu." << endl;

        cout << "=====================================================" << endl;
        cout << "\nChoose an option from the menu: ";
        cin >> option;
    }

    if (option == 5)
        cout << "End of program!" << endl;

}
```

This is the output of the program, after I enter the code it was terminated:

```
=================================
              MENU              
=================================
     1- Add new students
     2- Display student list
     3- Add new course
     4- Display Course Offered
     5- Exit Program
=================================

Choose an option from the menu: 3

How many courses do you want to enter? 2

Enter course 1 details: 
Course Code: 123
```

This is the output without using pointers, it was like this which is the output that I'm looking for:

```
=================================
              MENU              
=================================
     1- Add new students
     2- Display student list
     3- Add new course
     4- Display Course Offered
     5- Exit Program
=================================

Choose an option from the menu: 3

How many courses do you want to enter? 2

Enter course 1 details: 
Course Code: 0000
Course Name: course1     
Lecturer Name: lecturer1

Enter course 2 details: 
Course Code: 1111
Course Name: course2
Lecturer Name: lecturer2
=====================================================

Choose an option from the menu: 5
End of program!
```

Comment: `ptr[2] = &details[2];` invokes *undefined behavior*. Both arrays only have valid indices of 0 and 1

Comment: In `ptr[2] = &details[2];`, you access both arrays out of bounds. You probably want a loop with `ptr[i] = &details[i]` in it.

Comment: What is the purpose of using pointers here? Their inclusion seems to be a needless complication.

Comment: `ptr[0]` and `ptr[1]` are uninitalized and don't point at a usable `Student` object.